# Trying to use php variable in sql select statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm combining 2 pieces of code that has been written by others. The page displays records from a mySql database and the variable I'm trying to use is already being displayed using the following code:

```
<span class="headLeft"><?php echo cleanData($this->RECIPE->name); ?>:</span>
```

The sql select statement is trying to use the name field for it's lookup.

```
SELECT 
  name
  , Round(Sum(i.calories)/1500*100,2) as calories
  , Round(Sum(protein)/525*100,2) as protein
  , Round(Sum(fat)/300*100,2) as fat
  , Round(sum(carbohydrate)/675*100,2) as carbohydrate
  , Round(sum(fiber)/30*100,2) as fiber
  , Round(sum(sugar)/375*100,2) as sugar
  , Round(sum(saturated_fat)/150*100,2) as saturated_fat
  , Round(sum(monounsaturated_fat)/150*2,2) as monsaturated_fat
  , Round(sum(Polyunsaturated_Fat)/150*2,2) as polyunsaturated_fat
  , Round(sum(cholesterol)/200*100,2) as cholesterol
  , Round(sum(sodium)/1300*100,2) as sodium
  FROM `mr_recipes` r 
  left join ingredients i on r.id = i.recipeid

   where name = ($this->RECIPE->name)
group by name
```

I can't quite get the variable to work. I can't use $name and I've tried wrapping it in single and double quotes.

Comment: please simplify your question and format code in code tags

Comment: Sorry, thought it was readable

Comment: you are confusing SQL with php code.    You can't define a php variable in mysql.  Also you are calling the variable before you declared it.  What is all that rounding for?

Comment: `SET @calories = Round(Sum(i.calories)/1500*100,2)`; this is how you define a variable in MySQL but you should handle your arithmetic in your php.

Comment: I suggest you take a look to this: [Bobby tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com). It has a good explanation on how to use prepared statements to pass values to SQL queries... and it's a simple guide on how to prevent *evil* things to happen when you do so

Comment: Try to print it first $this->RECIPE->name, then use it in your mysql query

Comment: First, I'm not trying to define the variable in SQL, the variable is already defined. I can print the $this->Recipe-> name and it appears correctly. I just need the syntax for using the php variable in the where clause. Second, I appreciate the SQL injection issue, I will look into changing it. Third, the examples all show using the $variablename in the SQL statement, but it doesn't work. $name is undefined. I'm not familar with all the $this->Recipe->name variable naming, but I somehow need it to pass the already defined variable, but can't get the syntax.

Comment: You have not shown us the php code you are using around the SQL statement.

Comment: I figured it out but I don't know if it's best practice. If I create a variable like $name = $this->Recipe->name, then in the where clause of the sql statement do where name = $name, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to prepared statements.
To prevent SQL Injections, do not concatenate SQL query and parameters.

You should use PDO it's safer.

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).